# Form handling in javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, design-patterns, model-view-controller, code-organization

I am bad at organizing my javascript code. I've build a js app that handles different type of orders of a bike renting app, like:

- customer orders
- maintenance orders
- transport orders
- etc.

Also the transport orders can have order sub-types:
 - internal transport
 - transport from customer
 - transport to customer

In my front end I have to deal with creating/updating any order type. All orders share some fields like:

- picking location
- delivery location
- employee
- start date
- appointment date
- etc.

At the beginning my two html forms create/update and the spaghetti code did just fine, but I got intro problems when each order type changed it's requirements and needed a different html view. 
On update, for example I load the order data into the update form and I configure the form view depending on the order type by hiding/showing inputs.

I took a look at js inheritance, factory pattern, mvc but I didn't get a clear big picture on how to implement all of this. Also I came across this article https://www.awwwards.com/build-a-simple-javascript-app-the-mvc-way.html. What should the view be represented by? What should the model be represented by?

So therefore I ask you how should I organize my js code in a reusable way? I am not using any js library or framework.

Update:

On the client I keep all my data in a DataTable. A row object looks like this:

```
{
DT_RowId:90,
appointment_date:{text: "", timestamp: ""},
customer_text:{text: "", id: "null"},
employee_text:{text: "Alin Ungurean", id: 1},
end_date:{text: "02.07.2018", timestamp: 1530516492},
from_address:{text: "Mülheim an der Ruhr, Deutschland", id: "null"},
id:90,
order_date:{text: "08.07.2018 00:00", timestamp: 1531000800},
start_date:{text: "02.07.2018", timestamp: 1530516492},
status_text:{text: "offen", id: 67},
to_address:{text: "44793 Bochum, Deutschland", id: 143},
type_text:{text: "Transport Intern", id: 1}
}
```

To edit an order I have an existing HTML `<form>` that contains all the specific `<input>` and `<select>`. Before filling in the edit form with the order data, first I must prepare the edit `<form>`, showing/hiding `<input>` depending to the order type.

```
var input_startDate = form.find('[name="input-startDate"]');
var input_endDate   = form.find('[name="input-endDate"]');
var input_appointmentDate = form.find('[name="input-appointmentDate"]');

input_startDate.prop('disabled',true).addClass('hidden');
input_endDate.prop('disabled',false).addClass('hidden');
input_appointmentDate.prop('disabled',false).removeClass('hidden');
```

After I am done with the `<form>` preparation I fill in the edit `<form>` like so:

```
form.find('[name="input-employee"]')
.val(orderHeader.employee.text)
.attr('data-key',orderHeader.employee.id);

form.find('[name="input-customer"]')
.val(orderHeader.customer.text)
.attr('data-key',orderHeader.customer.id);

form.find('[name="input-from"]')
.val(orderHeader.from_location.address)
.attr('data-key',orderHeader.from_location.id)
.attr('data-lat',orderHeader.from_location.latitude)
.attr('data-lng',orderHeader.from_location.longitude);
```

Initially I thought it is a good idea to have only one `<form>` for editing but now  each time I edit an order I have to adjust the `<form>` elements so that the user sees only the relevant fields for each order type.

So I think the problem is how to organize the code, because each order type requires a different view of the edit `<form>`. It became really hard to maintain the spaghetti code.

I am looking for opinions.

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: I'm having difficulty thinking of how to explain this, but your client side code should be able to query your data and import it generically. The most basic example is making a query like `SELECT * FROM USERS` in which your client then shows all the columns and rows in a table. After you do that, your code can be organized into components that utilize your queries in specific ways. ..

Comment: Updated the question